# Are there any scikit-learn tools useful for implementing a genetic algorithm?

Tags: scikit-learn, genetic-algorithm

I'm aware that genetic algorithms are a very general concept, so perhaps it doesn't make sense to have a scikit-learn function for them (at least, it doesn't seem to exist as of Feb 2015). However, it seems there are a few things, like

- Convergence criteria (when to continue search)
- Particular types of GAs like ESP (enforced sub-populations), EDA, etc.

are not specific to the particular GA domain. **Has anyone used tooling in scikit learn to facilitate writing a GA?**